# Express 0.03125 in normalized floating-point form using a 8-bit machine

Tags: floating-point, data-representation

Express `0.03125` in normalized floating-point form using a 8-bit machine; 1-bit for sign, 3-bit for
exponent, 4-bit for mantissa.

Exponent is stored in excess-3 format, and mantissa is adjusted to
one digit/bit before the radix point.

Oh sorry! It's my first post in stackoverflow, and Im not used to this kind of sites. My answer is 0 100 0001, and I dont know if it is correct or not. I think the sign is 0 since there is a positive value, and 100 is the exponent, for the mantissa, I try to do it as 0.03125*2 and so on, so I get the value of 00001 and 4 bit for mantissa so the answer for it is 0001.
Hope I have explained my way of doing this question clearly because my English is quite bad. Thank you guys for correcting my way of asking.

Comment: And your problem is what exactly? And what is your own attempts at solving it? This is not a 'make my homework' site.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow, It would be better if you post your attempt so that we could help to guide you to solve the problem..

Comment: So, what is it you can't do?

Comment: I'm sorry, edited my post already, hope you guys can help

Answer (score 1):

An "excess-3" exponent format (which would be expected from a 3-bit exponent), gives a [bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) of `2^(k - 1) - 1`, which is `(3)` for `(k = 3)` exponent bits.

This suggests you can represent an exponent in the range: `{-3, 4}`. That is, given the 3-bit exponent `(E)` pattern: `{000, 001, .., 111} = {0, 7}`, the exponent `(e)` is found by subtracting the bias. That's not quite the case, as `E = 0` implies: `e = 1 - bias`; a special value reserved for *subnormal* representations.

Using `E` to represent the stored bits of the exponent, and `e` to represent `E - bias`, we keep multiplying `(0.03125)` by 2 until we have a leading binary `1.xxxx` form, where this leading `1.` bit is *implicit* in a normalized floating-point number. The value given is (conveniently) a power of (2) in this case: `0.03125 = 1/32 = 2^(-5)`

`1.0000 x 2^(-5)` : can't store `(-5)` exponent.

Since the *implicit* leading `1.x` would give a minimum value of `1 x 2^-2 = 0.25`, we're not going to be able to use a *normalized* representation - as we can see:

`0.1000 x 2^(-4)` : can't store `(-4)` exponent.

`0.0100 x 2^(-3)` : can't store `(-3)` exponent.

---

Normalized numbers imply a leading bit, e.g., `1.xxxx`, which isn't actually stored. Values to the right are interpreted as `1/2`, `1/4`, `1/8`, `1/16`, etc., just as a decimal system interprets successive digits as fractions of `10`, `100`, `1000`, etc.

Which brings us to the encoding of denormalized or 'subnormal' values. The `E = 0` or `e = (-2)` is a special value implying the leading bit is `0`, which gives us the significand: `0.xxxx`

The exponent is still interpreted as `e = (-2)` -> `2^e = 1/4`. As such, the mantissa: `[0.]0010` gives us: `(1/8) * 2^e = 1/32 = 0.03125`.

This gives the ([denormalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)) 8-bit [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) representation: **[0][000][0010]** or: (00000010)

---

Q: can you show your previous answer: (01000001) gives the value: 2.125?